# Where is random.h in msys2

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I am using MSYS2 mingw 64 when compiling code that needs the header `random.h` I am trying to make that code work on both Linux and windows with the least amount of changes

```
#include <sys/random.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));


    return 0;
}
```

I ran this command `pacman -S msys2-runtime-devel` to download the `random.h`  header file and it is located in sys official [link](https://packages.msys2.org/package/msys2-runtime-devel)

on linux, the file is included using `#include <linux/random.c>` but I don't know what to use on windows or if I have to do something completely different

When I comment the first line I get this warning

```
main.c:10:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   10 |         srand(time(NULL));
      |         ^~~~~
```

Comment: won't include `stdlib.h` be enough?

Comment: `srand/rand` do not require`random.h`, these are in `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the linked documentation,

- [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) is declared in `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) is declared in `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Neither requires including `random.h` or `linux/random.c`.